# Conditional triggered transition with Anylogic

Tags: if-statement, transition, distance, anylogic

I have a model, where there is a =n agent that we want to change the state based on a condition.
my condition is that, the distance between the agent and another agent must be <= 411 before the state changes.
I have tried the following code in my condition field:

```
if (double distanceTo(getNearestAgent(main.Agent))<=411)
{
return true; 
}
```

i get the syntax errors : 
`misplaced construct(s)`, and `( expected`

What am I doing wrong ? Plz assist

Answer (score 0):

Since you clarified that "Agent" is the name of your population on Main, your code syntax is wrong. Try this instead:

```
if (distanceTo(getNearestAgent(main.Agent))<=411) {
    return true; 
}
```

btw: Be extremly careful with condition-based transitions, they might not trigger when the condition is actually satisfied. Read in the help and around the web to make sure you get it right. Or better: do not use them at all, they also eat performance unnecessarily

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for your reply. I have used the population name, sorry, maybe I didn't represent the code well. what I meant by "Agent" in my code is the "myPopulationName". //getNearestAgent(main.myPopulationName) that's exactly my code; but i still got the error msg.

Comment: by the way... I watched your conference on youtube about "Best practices for AnyLogcic"; very interesting and insightful.

Comment: ah, always post your real code, otherwise misunderstandings arise. See my revised answer, it is a simple syntax error I oversaw previously.